# I want to send a Multitouch（such as two fingers） command through the Android AOA protocol, how can I do it

Tags: android, usb, hid, touchscreen

I  have two Android phones now, named A and B, they are connected together via a USB cable, and two APKs are installed respectively, and they communicate through the AOA HID protocol
I want to send the touch command on device A to device B, so that B also has corresponding response
There is no problem with single finger touch now, but there is a problem with two fingers
I suspect my descriptors and the touch events I send are assembled incorrectly

Below is my key code and reference example

[text](http://aospxref.com/android-10.0.0_r47/xref/frameworks/base/tests/AccessoryDisplay/source/src/com/android/accessorydisplay/source/SourceActivity.java)

```
//register HID
    private static final int MULTITOUCH_DEVICE_ID = 0;
    private static final int MULTITOUCH_REPORT_ID = 1;
    private static final int MULTITOUCH_MAX_CONTACTS = 2;

    private final ByteBuffer mHidBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
    
    private UsbHid.Multitouch.Contact[] mMultitouchContacts;

    private void registerHid() {
        mLogger.log("Registering HID multitouch device.");

        mMultitouch = new UsbHid.Multitouch(MULTITOUCH_REPORT_ID, MULTITOUCH_MAX_CONTACTS,
                mSurfaceView.getWidth(), mSurfaceView.getHeight());

        mHidBuffer.clear();
        mMultitouch.generateDescriptor(mHidBuffer);
        mHidBuffer.flip();

        mLogger.log("HID descriptor size: " + mHidBuffer.limit());
        mLogger.log("HID report size: " + mMultitouch.getReportSize());

        final int maxPacketSize = mControlEndpoint.getMaxPacketSize();

        mLogger.log("Control endpoint max packet size: " + maxPacketSize);
        if (mMultitouch.getReportSize() > maxPacketSize) {
            mLogger.logError("HID report is too big for this accessory.");
            return;
        }

        int len = mAccessoryConnection.controlTransfer(
                UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT | UsbConstants.USB_TYPE_VENDOR,
                UsbAccessoryConstants.ACCESSORY_REGISTER_HID,
                MULTITOUCH_DEVICE_ID, mHidBuffer.limit(), null, 0, 10000);
        if (len != 0) {
            mLogger.logError("Device rejected ACCESSORY_REGISTER_HID request.");
            return;
        }

        while (mHidBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
            int position = mHidBuffer.position();
            int count = Math.min(mHidBuffer.remaining(), maxPacketSize);

            len = mAccessoryConnection.controlTransfer(
                    UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT | UsbConstants.USB_TYPE_VENDOR,
                    UsbAccessoryConstants.ACCESSORY_SET_HID_REPORT_DESC,
                    MULTITOUCH_DEVICE_ID, 0,
                    mHidBuffer.array(), position, count, 10000);
            if (len != count) {
                mLogger.logError("Device rejected ACCESSORY_SET_HID_REPORT_DESC request.");
                return;
            }
            mHidBuffer.position(position + count);
        }

        mLogger.log("HID device registered.");

        if (mMultitouchContacts == null) {
            mMultitouchContacts = new UsbHid.Multitouch.Contact[MULTITOUCH_MAX_CONTACTS];
            for (int i = 0; i < MULTITOUCH_MAX_CONTACTS; i++) {
                mMultitouchContacts[i] = new UsbHid.Multitouch.Contact();
            }
        }
    }
```

```
//device descriptor

final class UsbHid {
    private UsbHid() {
    }

    /**
     * Generates basic Windows 7 compatible HID multitouch descriptors and reports
     * that should be supported by recent versions of the Linux hid-multitouch driver.
     */
    public static final class Multitouch {
        private final int mReportId;
        private final int mMaxContacts;
        private final int mWidth;
        private final int mHeight;

        public Multitouch(int reportId, int maxContacts, int width, int height) {
            mReportId = reportId;
            mMaxContacts = maxContacts;
            mWidth = width;
            mHeight = height;
        }

        public void generateDescriptor(ByteBuffer buffer) {


            buffer.put(new byte[] {
                0x05, 0x0d,                         // USAGE_PAGE (Digitizers)
                0x09, 0x04,                         // USAGE (Touch Screen)
                (byte)0xa1, 0x01,                   // COLLECTION (Application)
                (byte)0x85, (byte)mReportId,        //   REPORT_ID (Touch)
                0x09, 0x22,                         //   USAGE (Finger)
                (byte)0xa1, 0x00,                   //   COLLECTION (Physical)
                0x09, 0x55,                         //     USAGE (Contact Count Maximum)
                0x15, 0x00,                         //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
                0x25, (byte)mMaxContacts,           //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (...)
                0x75, 0x08,                         //     REPORT_SIZE (8)
                (byte)0x95, 0x01,                   //     REPORT_COUNT (1)
                (byte)0xb1, (byte)mMaxContacts,     //     FEATURE (Data,Var,Abs)
                0x09, 0x54,                         //     USAGE (Contact Count)
                (byte)0x81, 0x02,                   //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
            });

            byte maxXLsb = (byte)(mWidth - 1);
            byte maxXMsb = (byte)((mWidth - 1) >> 8);
            byte maxYLsb = (byte)(mHeight - 1);
            byte maxYMsb = (byte)((mHeight - 1) >> 8);

            byte[] collection = new byte[] {
                0x05, 0x0d,                         //     USAGE_PAGE (Digitizers)
                0x09, 0x22,                         //     USAGE (Finger)
                (byte)0xa1, 0x02,                   //     COLLECTION (Logical)
                0x09, 0x42,                         //       USAGE (Tip Switch)
                0x15, 0x00,                         //       LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
                0x25, 0x01,                         //       LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
                0x75, 0x01,                         //       REPORT_SIZE (1)
                (byte)0x81, 0x02,                   //       INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
                0x09, 0x32,                         //       USAGE (In Range)
                (byte)0x81, 0x02,                   //       INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
                0x09, 0x51,                         //       USAGE (Contact Identifier)
                0x25, 0x3f,                         //       LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (63)
                0x75, 0x06,                         //       REPORT_SIZE (6)
                (byte)0x81, 0x02,                   //       INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
                0x05, 0x01,                         //       USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
                0x09, 0x30,                         //       USAGE (X)
                0x26, maxXLsb, maxXMsb,             //       LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (...)
                0x75, 0x10,                         //       REPORT_SIZE (16)
                (byte)0x81, 0x02,                   //       INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
                0x09, 0x31,                         //       USAGE (Y)
                0x26, maxYLsb, maxYMsb,             //       LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (...)
                (byte)0x81, 0x02,                   //       INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
                (byte)0xc0,                         //     END_COLLECTION
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < mMaxContacts; i++) {
                buffer.put(collection);
            }
            buffer.put(new byte[] {
                (byte)0xc0,                         //   END_COLLECTION
                (byte)0xc0,                         // END_COLLECTION
            });
        }

        public void generateReport(ByteBuffer buffer, Contact[] contacts, int contactCount) {
            // Report Id
            buffer.put((byte)mReportId);
            // Contact Count
            buffer.put((byte)contactCount);

            Log.e("renrui","generateReport contacts.length:"+contacts.length+
                    " contactCount:"+contactCount+"  mMaxContacts:"+mMaxContacts);

            for (int i = 0; i < contactCount; i++) {
                final Contact contact = contacts[i];
                // Tip Switch, In Range, Contact Identifier
                buffer.put((byte)((contact.id << 2) | 0x03));
                // X
                buffer.put((byte)contact.x).put((byte)(contact.x >> 8));
                // Y
                buffer.put((byte)contact.y).put((byte)(contact.y >> 8));
            }


            for (int i = contactCount; i < mMaxContacts; i++) {
                buffer.put((byte)0).put((byte)0).put((byte)0).put((byte)0).put((byte)0);
            }
        }

        public int getReportSize() {
            return 2 + mMaxContacts * 5;
        }

        public static final class Contact {
            public int id; // range 0..63
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }
    }
```

```
//Send the touch event of device A to device B through AOA

   mSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                sendHidTouch(event);
                return true;
            }
        });

    private void sendHidTouch(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mMultitouchEnabled) {

            mLogger.log("Sending touch event: " + event);

            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    final int pointerCount =
                            Math.min(MULTITOUCH_MAX_CONTACTS, event.getPointerCount());

                    final int historySize = event.getHistorySize();

                   
                    for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
                        mMultitouchContacts[p].id = event.getPointerId(p);
                        mMultitouchContacts[p].x = (int)event.getX(p);
                        mMultitouchContacts[p].y = (int)event.getY(p);
                        Log.e("renrui","event.getPointerId("+p+"):"+event.getPointerId(p));
                    }
                    for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {
                        for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
                            mMultitouchContacts[p].x = (int)event.getHistoricalX(p, h);
                            mMultitouchContacts[p].y = (int)event.getHistoricalY(p, h);
                        }
                    
                        sendHidTouchReport(pointerCount);
                    }

                    for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
                        mMultitouchContacts[p].x = (int)event.getX(p);
                        mMultitouchContacts[p].y = (int)event.getY(p);
                    }
               
                    sendHidTouchReport(pointerCount);
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.e("renrui","ACTION_UP sendHidTouchReport(0)");
                    sendHidTouchReport(0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    private void sendHidTouchReport(int contactCount) {
        mHidBuffer.clear();
        mMultitouch.generateReport(mHidBuffer, mMultitouchContacts, contactCount);
        mHidBuffer.flip();

        int count = mHidBuffer.limit();

        byte[] bytes = mHidBuffer.array();

        int len = mAccessoryConnection.controlTransfer(
                UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT | UsbConstants.USB_TYPE_VENDOR,
                UsbAccessoryConstants.ACCESSORY_SEND_HID_EVENT,
                MULTITOUCH_DEVICE_ID, 0,
                bytes, 0, count, 10000);
        if (len != count) {
            mLogger.logError("Device rejected ACCESSORY_SEND_HID_EVENT request.");
            return;
        }
    }
```

I really don't know what to do, hope a hero will show up to help me，Thanks!!